# How to minimize distance traveled by n people over m locations

Tags: algorithm

This is a real-life problem, not homework.
I'll use specific numbers in the question.

My client has a very large warehouse with 16,000 locations.
They want to physically count the quantity in 200 locations, selected randomly, to verify the quantity the computer system has is accurate.

I know how to select exactly 200 locations at random (Knuth TAOCP).

The distance between locations is easy to calculate. The warehouse is arranged in aisles (like a big box store). Basically, what I learned as the taxi-cab metric (delta X + delta Y).

Assume they will assign 4 people to this task. How do I generate a list of locations for each person that will minimize the total distance traveled by the people?

For the general algorithm, the number of locations to be counted and the number of people assigned to the task would be input parameters.

To help you answer, I have decades of experience, but I am self-taught. I'm guessing this is a good problem for dynamic programming (watched the MIT lecture series recently), but have never implemented that. Stuck on forming the recursion.

Or maybe some other algortihm. It's not a ton of data points, so maybe a brute force approach?

If other tags are appropriate, please suggest them.
If you care to post code snippets, any language is fine.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I wonder if clustering the set of locations into four clusters, based on the distance, and assigning one person to each would work.

Comment: Maybe a modified version of undirected hamiltonian cycle mixed with djikstra's where the edges between nodes have a distance and instead of one worker trying to connect all the nodes, you have 4, and they're trying to all find the shortest distance needed to do so?

Comment: Do you need a provably optimum solution?  Since this is a real-world problem, I suspect that a very good solution would suffice.  Do you need to minimize the total distance, or the maximum distance traveled by any one inventory worker?

Comment: You have a restricted version of the traveling salesman problem.  Research that.  The modification for having four workers should be minimal.

Comment: @Prune Total cost to the client is the total distance travelled by all 4 workers - they should be making product, not counting inventory. But you are correct, a non-optimal solution would suffice. I could do the traveling salesman and cut the list into 4, but then would need kludgey "adjustments". Don't want to send worker #1 1/2 mile to the other side of the warehouse to count a location that was close to the list I gave worker #2 - It's the multiple workers that make this problem hard for me. Plus, a general solution is a lot more fun. But I'll think more about being practical.

Comment: (In *real life*, you don't. People are fairly good at choosing good paths. And they would feel bossed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the "total cost" criterion and the random scattering of the locations, I expect that the optimal path will be to have one worker cover most or all of the 200 locations; the other 3 will count *only* isolated pockets of inventory that pop up near the start/end point, `S`.

For a general attack, I recommend that you send your four workers in different directions from `S`.  From there, take a greedy approach: find the location nearest to any of the four workers; send that worker to said point.  Continue until all locations are visited.  Note that you have `S` as both the first and last point for each worker.

Now, process each worker's route to minimize total distance traveled for that worker.

Finally, "perturb" each path.  Pick a random location and remove it from its path.  Re-assign it to the path with the least incremental cost for that location.  Continue this reassignment until you achieve, say 1000 iterations with no change of assignment.

Comment: This was very helpful. The problem got a little more complicated because the "cost" had to consider how long it took to count the items at each location (expecting to count 3 vs. 400 items), but I can build that into the algorithm. (changing "total cost" to the workers time rather than just the distance traveled).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a [multiple traveling salesman](https://neos-guide.org/content/multiple-traveling-salesman-problem-mtsp) problem. You can choose random locations in a preprocessing step, and add a token "starting" location.

There are a few model definition languages that will allow you to declare a formal model that can be passed to a solver. You may need a license for GAMS or AMPL. Julia's JuMP package is provides a nice and free model definition language that is pretty easy to use.

As a practical matter, you may need to minimize the max of individual travel times if the inventory checking is time sensitive.